# Haskell "where" indentation: why must it be indented past identifier?

Tags: haskell, indentation

This code:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

myInt :: String -> Int
myInt [] = error "bad input: empty string"
myInt (x:xs)
  | x == '-'  = -1 * myInt xs
  | otherwise = foldl convert 0 (x:xs)
  where convert acc x
        | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] = 10 * acc + digitToInt x
        | otherwise           = error ("bad input: not an int - " ++ [x])
```

Fails:

> Prelude> :l safeListFs.hs
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( safeListFs.hs, interpreted )
>
> safeListFs.hs:9:8: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.

But this version:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

myInt :: String -> Int
myInt [] = error "bad input: empty string"
myInt (x:xs)
  | x == '-'  = -1 * myInt xs
  | otherwise = foldl convert 0 (x:xs)
  where convert acc x
          | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] = 10 * acc + digitToInt x
          | otherwise           = error ("bad input: not an int - " ++ [x])
```

is ok:

> Prelude> :l safeListFs.hs
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( safeListFs.hs, interpreted )
>   Ok, modules loaded: Main.

I can't figure out why those two last indents matter.

Comment: This question is a good example of why I hate Haskell's whitespace syntax; it always feels unintuitive to me compared to, say, Python. Unfortunately, the only thing I dislike *more* is ugly curly brackets littering my code.

Comment: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.offside The offside rule seems intuitive to me.  You just have to stop thinking about blocks (like Python, which doesn't make sense in Haskell) and think instead about continuations of a declaration or expression.

Comment: Use a clever text editor and forget about weird identation rules.

Comment: I use vim. With haskell indentation. Still, it didn't help in this case.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Basically, Haskell notes the column where the first non-space character after `where` appears (in this case, the `c` of `convert`) and treats following lines beginning in that column as new definitions inside the `where`.

A line that continues the definition of the previous line (such as your `|` guards) must be indented to the right of *the first non-space character* (`c` in your code).

A line indented to the left of `c` would be outside the `where` (for example, the start of your next top-level function).

It's the column of the first character following `where` that is crucial, even if it's on a new line:

```
  where
    convert acc x
      | ...
    anotherFunction x y

    ^
```

Comment: ++ Wonderful, I couldn't jump on board of the other answers, this is much like what @arternave suggested recently in a comment, I think this explains the issue.

Answer (score 13):

> A nested context must be further indented than the enclosing context (n>m). If not, L fails, and the compiler should indicate a layout error.

From http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html.

This would also fail:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

myInt :: String -> Int
myInt [] = error "bad input: empty string"
myInt (x:xs)
| x == '-'  = -1 * myInt xs
| otherwise = foldl convert 0 (x:xs)
where convert acc x
        | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] = 10 * acc + digitToInt x
        | otherwise           = error ("bad input: not an int - " ++ [x])
```

Uh, I'm bad at explaining things. There's a new context after `where` keyword, because you can specify more than one function in there -- remember that your program begins with implicit `module Main where`, so I think it's logical to require function body to be indented, just like on the module level (compiler expects another identifier on columns M and N, and declaration bodies to be further indented).

```
fun = ...
^ where fun' = ...
M       ^
        N
        fun'' = ...
fun2 = ...
```

Comment: Although your answers is obviously correct, it doesn't target my particular confusion. Which was based on the assumption that nested scope indentation would start from 'where'. Whereas it actually starts from function name.

Comment: I still don't understand this: speak to why the OP's example that works, works, and why the example that doesn't work, doesn't.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand this: the function is under the module scope with 0 indents, but the where is under the module scope with 1 indent?

Answer (score 6):

Because you should always indent function definitions.
(In your case, all things started at same column in `where` are considered "same-level" definition).

Comment: Offtopic: I have a friend whose name is Andrei Poluektov

Comment: I still don't understand this answer, it seems in both examples **where** is right under the pipe ('|') and indented the same

Comment: @Evan, 'where' is properly indented in both cases. It is pipes after 'where' which produce the the error. Because they aren't properly indented against 'convert' (in the first example)