# Haskell equation roots compiling error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The following algorithm is supposed to calculate the 2nd degree equation root, but compiling it produces a compiling error.
I copied it from a tutorial.

```
2 roota.hs:5:20: parse error on input `='

roots (a,b,c) = 
        if d < 0 then error "sorry" else (x1, x2)
        where x1 = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
            x2 = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
            d = b * b - 4 * a * c
            e = - b / (2 *a)
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Isn't haskell wonderful - it makes even the copy+paste people think :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with indentation. Try

```
roots (a,b,c) = 
         if d < 0 then error "sorry" else (x1, x2)
         where
           x1 = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
           x2 = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
           d = b * b - 4 * a * c
           e = - b / (2 *a)
```

See also [a question about indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223468/haskell-where-indentation-why-must-it-be-indented-past-identifier) and and [an article from a Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Haskell/Indentation&oldid=2209925).

Answer (score 1):

the **where** need not be on a line by itself;  this works:

```
roots (a,b,c) = 
        if d < 0 then error "sorry" else (x1, x2)
        where x1 = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
              x2 = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
              d = b * b - 4 * a * c
              e = - b / (2 *a)
```

or even this:

```
roots (a,b,c) = 
        if d < 0 then error "sorry" else (x1, x2) where 
 x1 = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
 x2 = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
 d = b * b - 4 * a * c
 e = - b / (2 *a)
```