# Haskell syntax error in where

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm trying to make a function that takes a ByteString of 4 bytes and returns an Int from those 4 bytes

I get the syntax error `main.hs:6:25: parse error on input '='` but I can't figure out what's wrong with this:

```
bs2int :: B.ByteString -> Maybe Int
bs2int s 
    | B.length s == 4   = Just (first .|. second .|. third .|. fourth)
    | otherwise         = Nothing
    where words     = (B.unpack s)
        first   = (toIntegral (words !! 0)) :: Int -- this line
        second  = (toIntegral (words !! 1)) :: Int
        third   = (toIntegral (words !! 2)) :: Int
        fourth  = (toIntegral (words !! 3)) :: Int
```

EDIT: Tried aligning the where bits and I still get the same error, here's how it looks in Notepad++ with whitespace visible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRTai.png

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223468/haskell-where-indentation-why-must-it-be-indented-past-identifier

Comment: it's haskells layout rule (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) - try to indent all your definitions under where to be in-line with `words` (that is: `first`, `second`, ...)

Comment: I personally think that the best choice with a `where` is to start a new line after it unless you only have one definition in the `where`, then it's acceptable to keep it as `where newdef = ...`.  I'd still recommend going to the next line and indenting over to where you have `first` through `fourth`

Comment: Ah, you're using tabs.  Go into the Notepad++ settings and set it to replace tabs with spaces.  GHC sees tabs as 8 columns, but you have your editor set up for 4 columns.  Just use spaces in Haskell, it'll make your life much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have pointed out already that the error is caused by an alignment mistake which you can fix by aligning `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` with `words` -- i.e. moving them two columns to the right.

In addition to that I wanted to point out two things:

1. `words` is not a very fortunate name because it's the name of a standard library function in the Prelude.
2. You can get away without the `where` altogether by noticing that your code -- for bytestrings of length 4 -- unpacks the bytestring, then calls `toIntegral` on each element and then folds the list using `(.|.)`. I.e. I think you could also do something like

   ```
   bs2int' :: B.ByteString -> Maybe Int
   bs2int' s
       | B.length s == 4 = Just (foldr1 (.|.) . map toIntegral . B.unpack $ s)
       | otherwise       = Nothing
   ```