# Parse error on input 'if'

Tags: haskell, indentation

I can't seem to figure out why this code does not work:

```
sgetLine  =  do  x <- getChar
              if x == '\n' 
                 then do 
                  putChar x
                  return []
                 else do 
                  putChar '_'
                  xs <- sgetLine
                  return (x:xs)
```

and strangely enough, the code works when i do this

```
sgetLine  =  do { x <- getChar
            ; if  x == '\n' 
                then do 
                 putChar x
                 return []
                else do 
                 putChar '_'
                 xs <- sgetLine
                 return (x:xs)}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because whitespace is significant in Haskell. You need to either follow the indentation rules or use explicit braces and semicolons (as in your second code block). Here are two ways (there are others) to fix the first block:

```
sgetLine  =  do  x <- getChar
                 if x == '\n' 
                   then do 
                     putChar x
                     return []
                   else do 
                     putChar '_'
                     xs <- sgetLine
                     return (x:xs)

-- I prefer this one. In any case, it's just a matter of style, so YMMV.
sgetLine  =  do  
  x <- getChar
  if x == '\n' 
    then do 
      putChar x
      return []
    else do 
      putChar '_'
      xs <- sgetLine
      return (x:xs)
```

The lines in within a `do` block must be indented by the same amount, and also be indented to the right of the line with `do`. That way, the compiler can figure out where your `do` block begins and ends without you having to write explicit braces.

See also: [Haskell “where” indentation: why must it be indented past identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223468/2751851) The question is about `where` rather than `do`, but the general principle is the same, and the answers there cover it well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought I was aligning stuff properly but clearly not.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have set a five-space tabstop, which makes the `x <- getChar` and `if x == '\n'` lines appear lined up on your screen. However, the compiler uses eight-space tabstops, so the `if x == '\n'` line appears much more indented to the compiler.

You should use spaces for alignment, reserving tabs for indentation. (Many people will suggest using only spaces, [but I won't](http://dmwit.com/tabs).)

Comment: I think this was exactly my problem. Things looked aligned in my editor (but then when I cut and paste here .. it wasn't). The link is helpful. Thanks for your help.