# Indentation error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i'm new with functionnal programing, so please if someone could tell me where am i wrong: in a file named add.hs i wrote :

```
ha :: (Bool,Bool) -> (Bool,Bool)
ha (n,m) = ((n && m),((n || m) && not(n && m))) 


fa :: (Bool,Bool,Bool) -> (Bool,Bool)
fa (a,b,r) = (c,s) where
(y,x) = ha(a,b)
(z,s) = ha(x,r)
c =(y||z)
```

( I know that probably there is a more appropriate type than Bool, but I just wanted to test it )

this what I get when I load the file:
[outupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ofK.png)

Comment: You have to indent your program properly. Indentation in Haskell isn't optional.

Comment: Thank you for help, i didn't know that before (now there is no error ^^ )

Comment: @Abir, I don't mean to blow my own horn, but you should really accept an answer by clicking the tick underneath it if it satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just formatting and indentation:

```
ha :: (Bool, Bool) -> (Bool, Bool)
ha (n, m) = (n && m, (n || m) && not (n && m)) 


fa :: (Bool, Bool, Bool) -> (Bool, Bool)
fa (a,b,r) = (c,s)
  where
    (y,x) = ha (a, b)
    (z,s) = ha (x, r)
    c     =  y || z
```

Apart from the pointless bracket's that I've removed, you need to indent your `where` clause further than the column that the `where` is written. This is called the offside rule, and is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223468/haskell-where-indentation-why-must-it-be-indented-past-identifier).

---

On a side-note, you're not writing idiomatic Haskell. We would usually write `ha` like so:

```
ha :: Bool -> Bool -> (Bool, Bool)
ha n m = (n && m, (n || m) && not (n && m))
```

And `fa` like so:

```
fa :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> (Bool, Bool)
fa a b r = (c, s)
  where
    (y,x) = ha a b
    (z,s) = ha x r
    c     =  y || z
```